Unable to insert records in oracle database while Batch aggregator is set to 'Streaming'
This is the mule flow I created:

Here are the properties of Batch Aggregator connector:

Here is the bulk insert connector properties:

I am using the select connector to get records from database and then inserting these records in same database into another table. Now there are no errors and the flow debugs successfully. However, no records are inserted in the database. This is the response I get in postman:
{
    "creationTime": "2024-10-07T16:55:08.11",
    "recordCount": 16,
    "result": {
        "onCompletePhaseException": null,
        "loadingPhaseException": null,
        "totalRecords": 16,
        "elapsedTimeInMillis": 0,
        "failedOnCompletePhase": false,
        "loadedRecords": 16,
        "failedRecords": 0,
        "failedOnInputPhase": false,
        "successfulRecords": 0,
        "batchStepResults": {},
        "inputPhaseException": null,
        "processedRecords": 0,
        "failedOnLoadingPhase": false,
        "batchJobInstanceId": "cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8"
    },
    "id": "cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8",
    "ownerJobName": "batch-processingBatch_Job",
    "status": "EXECUTING"
}

Also, these are the logs in console:
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:08,137 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [more-mule-scopes].batch-processingFlow.BLOCKING @4ef5d017] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Created instance 'cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8' for batch job 'batch-processingBatch_Job'
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:08,145 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [more-mule-scopes].batch-processingFlow.BLOCKING @4ef5d017] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Starting loading phase for instance 'cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8' of job 'batch-processingBatch_Job'
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:08,173 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [more-mule-scopes].batch-processingFlow.BLOCKING @4ef5d017] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Finished loading phase for instance cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8 of job batch-processingBatch_Job. 16 records were loaded
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:08,173 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [more-mule-scopes].batch-processingFlow.BLOCKING @4ef5d017] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Started execution of instance 'cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8' of job 'batch-processingBatch_Job'
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,131 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=7458, EMP_NAME=Lil Wayne, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=50, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,131 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=103, EMP_NAME=emp3, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=45, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,131 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=1123, EMP_NAME=Cardi B, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=48, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,146 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=101, EMP_NAME=emp1, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=52, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,146 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=2345336, EMP_NAME=Dhananjay Pareek, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=40, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,150 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=667676, EMP_NAME=Kendrick, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=45, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,150 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=104, EMP_NAME=emp4, EMP_STATUS=inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=55, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,150 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=7778, EMP_NAME=Biggie, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=49, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,150 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=102, EMP_NAME=emp2, EMP_STATUS=inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=44, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,157 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=105, EMP_NAME=emp5, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=50, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,157 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=6666, EMP_NAME=Rakim, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=47, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,157 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=106, EMP_NAME=emp6, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=53, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,162 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=3245, EMP_NAME=Kendrick Lamar, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=38, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,162 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=122365, EMP_NAME=Aram, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=40, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,162 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=5897, EMP_NAME=J. Cole, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=45, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,162 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Btach step -------------->>>>> {EMP_ID=1012, EMP_NAME=Drake, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=48, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,189 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.DefaultBatchStep: Step Batch_Step finished processing all records for instance cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8 of job batch-processingBatch_Job
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,210 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/aggregator/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: batch aggregator ----------------->>>>>>>> <<Non repeatable iterator>>
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:10,210 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [more-mule-scopes].batch-processingFlow.CPU_INTENSIVE @4f997413] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/5; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: testPayload end log---------------->>>>>>>>> []
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,668 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/aggregator/processors/3; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: stream test ------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>> null
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,668 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [more-mule-scopes].batch-job-batch-processingBatch_Job-work-manager @59264e49] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/0/route/0/aggregator/processors/4; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: testPayload in batch aggregator ---------->>>>>>>> [{EMP_ID=7458, EMP_NAME=Lil Wayne, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=50, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=103, EMP_NAME=emp3, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=45, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=1123, EMP_NAME=Cardi B, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=48, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=101, EMP_NAME=emp1, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=52, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=2345336, EMP_NAME=Dhananjay Pareek, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=40, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=667676, EMP_NAME=Kendrick, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=45, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=104, EMP_NAME=emp4, EMP_STATUS=inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=55, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=7778, EMP_NAME=Biggie, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=49, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=102, EMP_NAME=emp2, EMP_STATUS=inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=44, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=105, EMP_NAME=emp5, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=50, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=6666, EMP_NAME=Rakim, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=47, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=106, EMP_NAME=emp6, EMP_STATUS=active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=53, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=3245, EMP_NAME=Kendrick Lamar, EMP_STATUS=Inactive, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=38, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=122365, EMP_NAME=Aram, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=40, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=5897, EMP_NAME=J. Cole, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=45, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}, {EMP_ID=1012, EMP_NAME=Drake, EMP_STATUS=Active, EMP_APPR_YEAR=2020-2021, EMP_APPR_PER=48, EMP_SALARY=null, EMP_AGE=null}]
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,684 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [more-mule-scopes].batch-management-work-manager @52b62011] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Starting execution of onComplete phase for instance cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8 of job batch-processingBatch_Job
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,684 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [more-mule-scopes].batch-management-work-manager @52b62011] [processor: batch-processingFlow/processors/3/route/1/processors/0; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: testPayload on complete ---------------->>>>>>>>> []
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,684 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [more-mule-scopes].batch-management-work-manager @52b62011] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Finished execution of onComplete phase for instance cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8 of job batch-processingBatch_Job
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,684 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [more-mule-scopes].batch-management-work-manager @52b62011] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Finishing execution for instance 'cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8' of job 'batch-processingBatch_Job'.
INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,684 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [more-mule-scopes].batch-management-work-manager @52b62011] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: 

INFO  2024-10-07 16:55:11,700 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [more-mule-scopes].batch-management-work-manager @52b62011] [processor: ; event: cce58db1-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Finished execution for instance 'cece4ae0-849e-11ef-9039-fe4482d0d4c8' of job 'batch-processingBatch_Job'. Total Records processed: 16. Successful records: 16. Failed Records: 0

Look at the final log above (it shows successful records)
Now, if I uncheck the 'Streaming' checkbox under Batch aggregator properties then the records are successfully inserted into the table.
I tried checking the 'Preserve Mime types' checkbox and I also tried to coerce the payload in the Bulk Insert connector's 'Input Parameters' section like this: "payload as Array". But nothing seems to work.
I do not have much idea about how exactly streaming works in batch aggregator connector as I am new to this.
This is the xml of the flow:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="7afcf396-023d-4d04-a062-ca056ec9dccd" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="b7c7ee6f-4737-4020-aa98-2765326cc0b4" >
        <db:oracle-connection host="localhost" user="SYSTEM" password="briskminds" instance="XE" />
    </db:config>
    <flow name="batch-processingFlow" doc:id="5e48f637-d9c8-4743-85d5-72ebdb5b0a19" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="aa373718-3215-4ebc-bbdc-009da76c8766" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/batch-processing"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Start Log" doc:id="37b89179-4ba4-4a69-91b2-57012dde9c1c" />
        <set-variable value="#[[] as Array]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="4a10f7d3-6d6b-4843-bb18-3480e3da8eee" variableName="testPayload"/>
        <db:select doc:name="Select" doc:id="7d4c11b6-747e-4d13-99ec-c962c84a6d32" config-ref="Database_Config">
            <db:sql >
                <![CDATA[SELECT 
    e.emp_id,
    e.emp_name,
    e.emp_status,
    a.emp_appr_year,
    a.emp_appr_per,
    f.EMP_SALARY,
    f.EMP_AGE
FROM 
    employees e
LEFT JOIN 
    emp_appr_master a ON e.emp_id = a.emp_id
LEFT JOIN 
    emp_finance_master f ON e.emp_id = f.EMP_ID
]]>
            </db:sql>
        </db:select>
        <batch:job jobName="batch-processingBatch_Job" doc:id="6e66a6b0-2b86-4909-9b64-1ad6ebc35cb2" blockSize="50">
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="83beea77-2e60-4ca4-82da-62f9f6188a68">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="519dad70-35a1-4bf7-b10f-8744f11a82ee" message="Btach step --------------&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; #[payload]"/>
                    <!-- [STUDIO:"Transform Message"]<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="e3f9bdf6-b098-4549-924c-ba42009ddd06" ><ee:message ><ee:set-payload >
                    <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
&#45;&#45;-
{
  ("EMP_ID": payload.EMP_ID) if(payload.EMP_ID != null),
  ("EMP_NAME":payload.EMP_NAME) if(payload.EMP_NAME != null),
  ("EMP_STATUS": payload.EMP_STATUS) if(payload.EMP_STATUS != null),
  ("EMP_APPR_YEAR":payload.EMP_APPR_YEAR) if(payload.EMP_APPR_YEAR != null),
  ("EMP_APPR_PER":payload.EMP_APPR_PER) if(payload.EMP_APPR_PER != null),
  ("EMP_SALARY":payload.EMP_SALARY) if(payload.EMP_SALARY != null),
  ("EMP_AGE": payload.EMP_AGE) if(payload.EMP_AGE != null)
}
&#93;&#93;></ee:set-payload></ee:message></ee:transform> [STUDIO] -->
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" doc:id="a0519d36-db6a-4e65-abba-4c4aea4f4659" streaming="true">
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="1f84710c-7951-4693-bf39-94eecbdf5e2f" message="batch aggregator -----------------&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; #[payload]"/>
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="207b74c6-9a36-4fe9-a0cd-8d558b6bd7a4" >
                            <ee:message ></ee:message>
                            <ee:variables >
                                <ee:set-variable variableName="testPayload" >
                                    <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
vars.testPayload ++ payload as Array]]>
                                </ee:set-variable>
                            </ee:variables>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <db:bulk-insert doc:name="Bulk insert" doc:id="33baf059-dd64-4b62-b077-822e6865d467" config-ref="Database_Config">
                            <db:sql>
                                <![CDATA[INSERT INTO random_table (EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_STATUS, EMP_APPR_YEAR, EMP_APPR_PER, EMP_SALARY, EMP_AGE) 
VALUES (:EMP_ID, :EMP_NAME, :EMP_STATUS, :EMP_APPR_YEAR, :EMP_APPR_PER, :EMP_SALARY, :EMP_AGE)
]]>
                            </db:sql>
                        </db:bulk-insert>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="57557ceb-330f-47fc-a3f8-caa15ca2e48c" message="stream test -------------------------&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; #[payload.EMP_ID]"/>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c82b60af-0a8a-42fb-ab61-25ccd8c8810c" message="testPayload in batch aggregator ----------&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; #[vars.testPayload]"/>
                    </batch:aggregator>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="6ae18981-19aa-43c8-a4df-0e64b0d5fd0c" message="testPayload on complete ----------------&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; #[vars.testPayload]" />
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="059f352c-ae9f-4c4c-b61e-1e5519b3b79a" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload >
                    <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]>
                </ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="End Log" doc:id="c96a2035-5241-49b6-8a82-72836f76142f" message="testPayload end log----------------&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt; #[vars.testPayload]"/>
    </flow>
</mule>

What could be the reason for this?
If you need more specific details about the flow then please let me know.
Thanks

Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly

Also, add more lines from the console output. Try to include logs from the loggers that you have places (start logger, end logger etc)

Hi, Those logs are not useful, still I have added them. Also, I have already added the images

It may not be useful to you as you have tried executing the process multiple times. But for someone who will look at it for the first time it is. without it I cannot tell if the batch commit part was ever executed or not. Or maybe it was executed and stopped at the db insert phase. There maybe error that you have missed. The code is important so that others can look exactly what are you doing. I do not know how are you inserting the data in DB. If I want to try it out I can not just copy from your example. You should try to provide a MVP of your problem to make it easier for others to help you

For longer text parts, you can add a triple tick (```) to make it scrollble

Thanks for letting me know this. I am new to this platform. I have edited the question accordingly. I have also added the bulk insert connector's properties screenshot

The bulk insert operation was an example. What I wanted to tell is the XML snippet of the flow will be required to tell where the problem is exactly. Since you are using "streaming", it is possible that you may be consuming the payload in one of the earlier operations, making the payload inaccessible for the bulk insert operation. But without the code one can only guess. If it helps, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

As @HarshankBansal exlplained copy the XML of the flow into your question and use [code block] for XML, code, logs, and other formatted text information.

Hi, I have added the xml of the flow in the end. Please check it out
